# Package body: xlsx_builder_pkg / ORA-06502: number or value error: text buffer too small

Tags: oracle, ora-06502

I use package: xlsx_builder_pkg (export data to excel file from some statement).
I added an attachments:

- xlsx_builder_pkg.pkb
- xlsx_builder_pkg.pks

I try to export all the data from institution table to Excel file with one sheet named country.

I receive follwing errors:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: number or value error: text buffer too small
ORA-06512: "SYS.XLSX_BUILDER_PKG", line 1646
ORA-06512: "SYS.XLSX_BUILDER_PKG", line 1870
```

The statement I run:

```
BEGIN
xlsx_builder_Pkg.clear_workbook;
xlsx_builder_pkg.new_sheet ('country');
xlsx_builder_pkg.query2sheet (p_sql => '**SELECT distinct name FROM system.institution where rownum < 500**', p_sheet => 1);    
xlsx_builder_pkg.save ('country', 'country.xlsx');
END;
```

But if I use statement `'**SELECT distinct name FROM system.institution where rownum < 400**'` it works perfect.
I think there is limit of file size. But in what way I could change it.

According to errors I think the problem is somewhere in function finish

```
ORA-06512: "SYS.XLSX_BUILDER_PKG", line 1646
ORA-06512: "SYS.XLSX_BUILDER_PKG", line 1870
```

The line 1646 tells the problem with `t_tmp := t_tmp || t_str;`

I use package and package body from this:
https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils/blob/master/ora/xlsx_builder_pkg.pkb

and

https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils/blob/master/ora/xlsx_builder_pkg.pks

Comment: Presumably you're using some variant of [this](https://github.com/commi235/xlsx_builder), or something it's based on, or something derived from it. But the line numbers of the concatenation you've mentioned don't match that specific one. (It looks like it's handling CLOBs better than concatenation suggests too.) We can't see the code you're actually running; and if you've got it from a repo like that then maybe check if you have the latest version and checks for bugs, or report one, against that. (Also not sure this should really be installed as SYS?)

Comment: I add in the main topic the links from where I use the package and package body.

Comment: That doesn't seem to match either, though line 1853 does do that concatenation. It looks like it's trying to protect that that, in that version. Anyway - if you have an issue with code you are getting from somewhere else then you really need to take that up with the maintainers of that code. Or, change to a different version or implementation.

Comment: (unrelated) please dont build/put stuff in the SYSTEM account. Create your own user account and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using 2-byte encoding in the database?
Please change all places in package from > 32000 to > 16000.

```
For example line 1638 
     old: if t_len > 32000 
     new: if t_len > 16000
```

For me helped for error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: number or value error: text buffer too small
error ORA-06512: on  "SIEBEL_CHECK.XLSX_BUILDER_PKG", line 1853

in line 1848 I changed
     old: if length( t_tmp ) + length( t_str ) > 32000
     new: if length( t_tmp ) + length( t_str ) > 16000
```